# iOS static html page in iframe half showing

Tags: html, iframe, ios5, scroll, touch

I have this iframe showing a static html page in iOS safari (iPad), the beginning of the html page loading in the iframe shows all right, but when I scroll a bit down, it suddenly shows off, like it was masked or whipped and white ... ??
I can't find any response to this issue... any idea ?

here's a small link to see : http://past.is/2PIL

and here's the basic code i'm using :

```
<style type="text/css">
#boite iframe {
max-width: 100%;}

#boite {
left: 50px;
top: 68px;
height: 520px;
width: 600px;
position:relative;
overflow:scroll;
border: thin solid red;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;}

</style>
<div id="boite"><iframe src="shopingpath.html" width="728" height="1500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Your CSS is declaring values of the frame, when you are re-defining them in the iframe code, too. Try either removing your CSS decloration for iframe, or the width, height parameters in your iframe.

Comment: thank-you for your reply, and i'm sorry i mixed up my question, please read it again, i have made some changes, and this should normally work but still i have this bug opening this page on iPad - see link to my example too (if you have an iPad around) : http://past.is/2PIL

Comment: This is an odd problem - I'm experiencing it too. If you can interact with the "new" content in any way, it seems to refresh and draw itself properly. Interacting could be zooming in, highlighting text that you know is there (even though it appears white), etc. If I can find a solution I will post it.